# Disnake - отправляет ошибку после нажатия кнопки

Tags: python, бот, discord, disnake

всем привет! я хотел сделать команду, чтобы вызывать Порфирьевич. код ну вроде должен работать, он работает. но вот если прям быстро нажать, то будет ошибка `disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction`

ещё может выдать `<disnake.embeds.Embed object at 0x0000021C1F7411B0>`(хотя я эмбед даже не использую). пытался решить как-то сам, но не получилось. буду рад, если кто-то поможет, заранее спасибо

сам же код(не бейте):

````py
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands
import requests
import random
from disnake.ui import Button

class skynet(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    async def generate_otvet(self, inter: disnake.ApplicationCommandInteraction, text: str):
        url = 'https://pelevin.gpt.dobro.ai/generate/'
        headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36',
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'Origin': 'https://porfirevich.ru',
            'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
            'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
            'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
            'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'
        }
        data = {
            'prompt': f'{text}',
            'length': random.randint(5, 100)
        }

        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            result = response.json()

            await inter.message.edit(content=f"{text}**{result['replies'][0]}**", components=[Button(emoji="", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.grey, custom_id="rewrite")])
        else:
            await inter.message.edit(content=f'Ошибочка ¯\_(ツ)_/¯')

    @commands.slash_command(dm_permission=False)
    async def porfirevich(self, inter: disnake.ApplicationCommandInteraction, text: str):
        """Генерирует текст с помощью Порфирьевича"""
        await inter.response.defer()
        await self.generate_otvet(inter, text)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_button_click(self, interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction):
        await interaction.response.defer()
        button_disabled = Button(emoji="<:loading:1182012529598279731>", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.grey, custom_id="rewrite", disabled=True)
        await interaction.message.edit(components=[button_disabled])

        if interaction.data.custom_id == "rewrite":
            original_text = interaction.message.content.split("**")[0]
            await self.generate_otvet(interaction, original_text)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(skynet(bot))```
````

Answer (score 0):

`requests` не предзначен для работы в асинхронных средах. Он блокирует event loop, а вместе с ним и слушатель событий. Используйте асинхронный [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) (установляется вместе с disnake, так что ничего делать не надо):
Пример:

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def main():

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('http://python.org') as response:

            print("Status:", response.status)
            print("Content-type:", response.headers['content-type'])

            html = await response.text()
            print("Body:", html[:15], "...")

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: все равно ошибка `disnake.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction`

а еще, знаете может как фиксануть `disnake.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 40060): Interaction has already been acknowledged.` ?

Answer (score -1):

Зачем вы используете ожидание в кнопках? Как по мне не логично, попробуйте изменить ответ на кнопку

```
@bot.listen("on_button_click")
async def button_lst(inter: disnake.MessageInteraction):
    if inter.component.custom_id not in ["rewrite"]:
        return
    if inter.component.custom_id == 'rewrite':
        original_text = interaction.message.content.split("**")[0]
            await self.generate_otvet(interaction, original_text)
```

Должно заработать, будут ошибки пишите в комментарии